# Где ошибка в коде игры?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pysimplegui

Python жалуется на программу с ошибкой

```
  File "C:/Users/undefinedMaster/Documents/Угадайка/game.py", line 7, in <module>
    [sg.Text(text='Ваш выбор'), sg.InputText()]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Button
```

Вот сам код:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import random
closeIco = b'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'
sg.theme('Light Grey')
lay = [[sg.Button(button_text='',image_data=closeIco,key='exit'),sg.Text('Угадайка')],
       [sg.Text('Угадай число')],
       [sg.Text(text='Ваш выбор'), sg.InputText()]
       [sg.Button(button_text='OK')]]
window = sg.Window('Угадайка',layout,no_titlebar=True)
solved = False
solve = random.randint(1,10)

while True:
    if solved == True:
        solved = False
        solve = random.randint(1,10)
    event,values = window.read()
    
    if event in ('Exit',sg.WIN_CLOSED):
        break
window.close()
```

Comment: Запятую в конце указанной в сообщении об ошибке строчки пропустили.

Comment: @GrAnd спасибо, плюс еще там были другие ошибки. (я их решил)